# How to add a server name to a discord.py command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Hello**
I was wondering how I can add in my bots kick command and the rest, the server name or (Guild) they were kicked/baned/warned. From or in...

This is in DM's and the channel the command was used...

My Code:

```
@client.command(aliases=['w'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx,member : discord.Member,*,reason = "Reason Not Provided"):
    """ Kick a member, Moderator only."""
    await member.send("You have been kicked from #### | "+reason)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Where the #### is, is where I wanna put the server name.

Comment: The guild name is available as part of the [command context/ctx](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context). You'll need to format the message before executing `member.send()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work

```py
@client.command(aliases=['w'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx,member : discord.Member,*,reason = "Reason Not Provided"):
    """ Kick a member, Moderator only."""
    await member.send("You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name} | {reason}")
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: I know more about python now, but from what I have learned you need to put it like this

`await member.send(f"You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name} | {reason}")`

and create an (f) string.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, but yes that is correct. I forgot to add the "f".